# Find the value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega (t+t_0))}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Question:**

For $\omega>0$, you are given that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt = \frac{4\pi\omega}{\sinh (\pi\omega)}$$

Find the value of

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos \big(\omega (t+t_0) \big)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt$$

where $t_0 \in \Bbb R$ is a constant.

---

**Attempt:**

The obvious thing to try is to substitute $u = t+t_0$. But of course, this is not going to work because you can't deal with the $\cosh^2 ((u-t_0)/2)$ term in the denominator.

I then tried to use compound angle formula for cosine, which gives

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos \big(\omega (t+t_0) \big)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt = \cos(\omega t_0) \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (\omega t)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt}_{=\dfrac{4\pi \omega}{ \sinh(\pi\omega)}} - \sin(\omega t_0)\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (\omega t)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt$$

But that simply changes the problem into finding

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (\omega t)}{\cosh^2(t/2)}\, dt$$

instead, which isn't any easier.

I also tried doing complex integration by considering $\frac{\exp{(i\omega t)}}{\cosh^2 (t/2)}$ and the semi-circle contour, but that got really messy...

Any hints?

Comment: The thing with sine function is zero, because you have an odd integrand, right?

Comment: Omg, you're right! I feel so stupid now...